# Using define or static var?

Tags: php, oop, static, constants

I'm currently updating my personal PHP framework and I have a question: what is the best way to store config variables in oop style?

In fact, I'm currently using define vars like this, because I always read that define vars are good as config vars:

```
define('LOG_FILE', 'app/log/log.txt');
```

But in an oop way, isn't it better to use a static class with static vars?

```
MyFramework::LOG_FILE = 'app/log/log.txt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common accepted way to keep configs in Frameworks is to keep in registry ([Registry Design Pattern explained in PHP](http://avedo.net/101/the-registry-pattern-and-php/))

So that, you may create config.yaml or config.json or any other format you feel convenient to use. Then core of you framework will parse it and store in Registry.
Registry by the principle is static so that makes it available "worldwide" around your framework.
Also registry works a way of internal caching, to not read, parse, store the objects again and again.

At any step you may get config this way:

```
$config = Registry::get('config');
```

Comment: It's never late to learn, mate. Hope it helps. ;-)